# Where did Rilke say or write "The purpose of life is to be defeated by greater and greater things"?

Tags: quote-source, german-language, rainer-maria-rilke

> The purpose of life is to be defeated by greater and greater things.

This quote is widely attributed to the German poet Rainer Maria Rilke, but I cannot find the source. Where did he say or write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be from the poem "Der Schauende", variously translated into English as "The Man Watching" or "The Beholder". The [original German text](http://martyrion.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/man-watching-der-schauende-by-rainer.html) of this quote is:

> Die Siege laden ihn nicht ein.
>   Sein Wachstum ist: der Tiefbesiegte
>   von immer Größerem zu sein.

It's been translated into English in a number of ways, including:

- > Winning does not tempt that man.
  >   This is how he grows: by being defeated, decisively,
  >   by constantly greater beings.
  >
  > <sub>-- [Robert Bly translation](http://www.poetry-chaikhana.com/blog/2015/06/05/rainer-maria-rilke-the-man-watching/)</sub>
- > Winning does not tempt that man.
  >   His growth is this: to be defeated
  >   by ever greater forces.
  >
  > <sub>-- [Anita Barrows and Joanna Macy translation](http://yearwithrilke.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/man-watching-ii.html)</sub>
- > His growth is: to be the deeply defeated
  >   by ever greater things.
  >
  > <sub>-- [Edward Snow translation (apparently)](http://yearwithrilke.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/man-watching-ii.html)</sub>

---

*I think I got lucky finding this. When I searched Google for "rilke The purpose of life is to be defeated by greater and greater things", most of the results were lists of Rilke quotes including this as a platitude, like [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9371-the-purpose-of-life-is-to-be-defeated-by-greater) and [Brainyquote](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/rainer_maria_rilke_147753), but one or two hits mentioned this poem, including [this blog post](http://yearwithrilke.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/man-watching-ii.html), which gave me the name of the poem I needed to search for to find out more.*

Comment: Just thought I'd add that the third translation is closest to the original.